# How to check for Map object keys in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Using Jest, I am trying to check for keys in a JavaScript Map object and `toHaveProperty` does not work. In Mocha/Chai you can `assert.hasAllKeys(map, keys)`

JavaScript Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`toHaveProperty` is meant for checking paths on a plain javascript object. There aren't any built in matchers (that i'm aware of) that specialize in Map objects, so i'd recommend doing something like this:

```
expect(myMapObject.has(key)).toEqual(true)
```

Comment: This works. I tried `.toBeTruthy` as well and it worked. Thanks for the answer. I am moving from Mocha/Chai and Jest is a little lacking compared to Chai/Mocha for certain things.

Comment: @Kainan unless I'm misunderstanding and chai/mocha have matchers for Map, this is a question about Javascript objects with no blame on the test library.

Comment: @stealtheninja Mocha/Chai can take an array of keys and check if they exist in a Map using `assert.hasAllKeys(map, keys)`. In this case, Jest comes up short IMO.